# Show Hide div in Chrome Extension popup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, popup, google-chrome, hide, show

I've been trying to make an option show and hide(possibly toggle) in my browser action popup without success. 
The code below is the body of my popup

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<div class="show">
    <a href="#" class="showcontent">Show</a>
    <a href="#" class="hidecontent">Hide</a>
    <div class="somecontent">
        <p>some content<br />
            <a href="#">Link</a><br />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The popup.js file contains, among other things:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".somecontent").hide();
    $(".showcontent").click(function(){
        $(".somecontent").show();
    });

    $(".hidecontent").click(function(){
        $(".somecontent").hide();
    });
});
```

I believe the problem is that the Chrome API is having problems with my popup.js file. The body appears in my popup but the Show and Hide actions do not work. Any ideas how to make this work and if not, another way to get the same result (ie: toggle on click)?

**EDIT:** From the javascript Console, the error I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of null

Which points to the line of the above code using the ready function.

Comment: have you fixed this? I had similar issues but fixed it by fixing the order the `<script/>` lines occured in the document (css, jquery script, other script)

Answer (score 11):

It's also possible that jQuery is conflicting with something else in your page for the use of the `$()` function. (I just ran into this problem myself.) If that's the case, changing the `$()` calls to `jQuery()` should solve the issue.

Comment: Haha! Delighted to hear that it helped, Jon. :)

Comment: Tnx for this answer this really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are neither returning false from your click handlers nor calling `preventDefault()`, the page will get reloaded on clicking and the `.somecontent` will be hidden again. Change your JS to following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".somecontent").hide();
    $(".showcontent").click(function(){
        $(".somecontent").show(); return false;
    });

    $(".hidecontent").click(function(){
        $(".somecontent").hide(); return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Though that did fix some of the errors, I'm left with this one:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of null

Which is from the jQuery $(document).ready(function(){... at the beginning of my popup.js code

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

probably popup.js is causing a parse/exec error? try seeing if chrome can print errors with:

> JavaScript Console: click the Page
>   menu icon and select Developer -
>   JavaScript Console. From here, you'll
>   be able to view errors in the
>   JavaScript execution, and enter
>   additional JavaScript commands to
>   execute.
>
> JavaScript Debugger: available as Page
>   menu icon 0 Developer - Debug
>   JavaScript, the debugger provides a
>   command prompt from which you can set
>   breakpoints, backtrace, and more. Type
>   help at the debugger command line to
>   get started.

from [here](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/th/webmasters-faq.html)

that error you got could happen if jquery isn't loaded:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>alert($(document))</script>
```

it should popup the object...

Comment: Here's what it's giving me

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of null

Which is from the jQuery $(document).ready(function(){... at the beginning of my popup.js code

Thanks for the console tip by the way.

Comment: try the jquery.js alert document

Comment: After trying the alert document, I now only receive this error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hide' of null". The alert made a popup message appear with null inside.

Comment: seems like it's not loading jquery, what if you try http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js (the latest, hosted from google) as a test..?

Comment: That is what I tried unfortunately. The ready method "works" but once it gets to "hide" or "show" it gives me that error. :(

Answer (score 0):

That error means jQuery is not being loaded properly.  Check to make sure it's called jquery.js and stored in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me. As other said the error you're getting sounds like the jquery.js file isn't being found/loaded.
This is a long shot, but if you're on Windows check the properties of the jquery.js file and see if there's an *Unblock* button right on the first tab. Click it.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems this old question is still not answered I thought I'd try my luck.

Have you tried downloading jquery.js again (file might be corrupted). Also, if you are still interested in solving it, can you post your src somewhere for us to read (like http://jsfiddle.net/)